# iOS 13 - In-App Purchase doesn't work anymore?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase, ios13

Since some days, on my apps, the ratio in-app sales/users dropped completely on iOS 13 (8% users and <2% sales, probably renewals).

At the same time, I noticed on my iOS 13.7 iPhone that the IAPs no longer worked on any app, not just mine! On the other hand, purchases on the App Store, as well as IAPs in debug mode and on Testflight applications still work.

I updated my iPhone to iOS 14, and everything worked again.

Is there a problem with IAPs under iOS 13?

Thanks in advance !